# How to rename a set of files in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, rename

I have a Tapestry project where I have language dependent properties and other files

```
ls -alR | grep '_en\..*'
```

So the above gives me the list of results such as

```
Chat_en.properties
User_en.vm
Home_en.tml
```

Now I need to rename all those into **_zz** instead of **_en**. Is there any single command where I can rename those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Bash one-liner:

```
for f in *; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f//_en/_zz}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` when this prints what you need. It uses [substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) on the filename.

---

With the `rename` command that accepts Perl regular expressions you can also do:

```
rename -n 's/_en/_zz/' *
```

Remove the `-n` when you're sure it'll rename everything correctly.

Comment: Thankx. But now I when you say "f in *" it just get the files in folder where I execute it. How can i give the list "ls -alR | grep '_en\..*'" i got there ?

Comment: I figured it out . I added $(comman line) into that. Thank you again

Comment: Why do you need the `ls … | grep …` in there? The command will only rename files or folders that contain `_en` anyway. There's no need to filter them before or anything. It's a [bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for various reasons. You can just do `for f in /path/to/folder/*` too.